# Allow Enter Key To Make A New Line in when writing in WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

what happens is that im typing in a TextBox
I  want a new line created in the box if I Press Enter Key while writing the content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to set the `AcceptsReturn` property to true. More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.acceptsreturn(v=vs.95).aspx